# JavaFX Validación entrada enTextField mediante expresiones regulares

Tags: regex, javafx

Tengo que validar una serie de TextField en una aplicacion de JavaFX. Creo que la forma mejor sería expresiones regulares. Pero no estoy dando en el clavo. Necesito validar una entrada que no contenga más de 25 caracteres y que no contenga caracteres especiales como @#$€%€/()=?¿ etc. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
@FXML
    void handleMarca(KeyEvent event) {

        String m = txtMarca.getText()+event.getCharacter();

        if( m.length() > 25 || m.matches("[^ A-Za-z0-9]" )){

            ClaseAccesoria.dialogo("Escriba un nombre inferior a 25 caracteres.\n +
                 "Solo se admiten letras y dígitos.", ERROR);
          
        }else{
            Marca = txtMarca.getText();
        }
    }//fin metodo
```

Tal como he escrito la expresión regular diría que pone "rechazo a todo caracter que no sea A-Za-z0-9" Pero de momento los acepta sin problema. Me podría alquien indicar como hacer una expresión regular que no acepte caracteres especiales, o bien sólo acepte caracteres especiales y la niego.
Y ya si puedo incluir que sólo admita menos de 25 cracteres....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `matches` de java hace que la expresión regular lleve implícito un inicio y final de string.

Por lo tanto cuando usas la expresión regular

```
[^ A-Za-z0-9]
```

realmente lo que tienes es:

```
^[^ A-Za-z0-9]$
```

Así que siemplemente estás detectando como problemático los strings de más de 25 de longitud o los strings de un sólo caracter que no sea blanco o letras y números.

Si introduces en tu campo un único caracter debería fallar. Prueba con `-` por ejemplo.

Para utilizar `matches` y que te funcione, prueba a cambiar la expresión regular a lo siguiente:

```
.*[^ A-Za-z0-9].*
```

Otra versión un poco más eficiente (en caso de que el texto fuera muy largo) sería:

```
[ A-Za-z0-9]*[^ A-Za-z0-9].*
```

Pero lo más eficiente y lo que tiene más sentido es simplemente buscar cosas correctas (en lugar de incorrectas) y negar la condición de match:

```
! m.matches("[ A-Za-z0-9]*")
```

Donde

```
[ A-Za-z0-9]*
```

equivale a

```
^[ A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

por usar `matches`

Y por lo tanto quiere decir que el string debe cumplir que desde el inicio hasta el final se constituye de 0 o más (`*`) caracteres que pueden ser a-ZA-Z0-9 y blanco.

Al negarlo, es una manera de encontrar el resto de casos que no lo cumplen.

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias